# Actions on Google - "Sorry I can't help"

Tags: bots, actions-on-google, google-home

Recently, my application has stopped working on Actions on Google, with a message of "Sorry I can't help".  When viewing inside the simulator, i see a properly formatted response, with output messages that application sends, however, the response is "Sorry i can't help".  This doesn't happen on the same intent, it happens after having a conversation for a few minutes.  If i restart the intent, and ask the same question/intent, then the response is good, until a few minutes pass by, and then "Sorry I can't help" comes up again.

Comment: Please report your issue using the support form: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out you can only have "Default Fallback Intent" respond 3 times in a row, before the application closes.